# How do I improve the recording levels when rcording from mixer to laptop?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, usb

I'm an amateur when it comes to all things audio, but I've been put in charge of the audio system at our church.

We're making the switch from recording sermons directly to CD to recording to a laptop. I've set up our Mixer (a Phonic Impact II) so that one of its aux channels feeds into the laptop via a Berhinger USB audio interface ( a U202, IIRC). We're using Audacity to record.

Recording works OK if we use a lapel mic. In other words, we get a good level of signal showing up in audacity's waveform. But if we use our shotgun mics on the lectern, the signal is too quiet on the laptop (very low peaks in the waveform).

I've just installed two AKG C747s on the lectern in the hope that that would solve the problem, but it hasn't altered anything.

I've tried turning up the gain on the shotgun mics, but that hasn't helped. Neither does turning up the gain in audacity itself - it doesn't bring the signal to anywhere near the level of the lapel mic.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I put it right?

Comment: Just to be sure: you _have_ phantom power turned on, right?

Comment: I think so. We accidentally had the channel turned on when we plugged the microphone in, and it made a big bump of a noise. Would it do that if phantom power wasn't on?

Comment: Also, we can hear the output from the shotgun mics fine over the speakers: would we be able to if phantom power was off?

Comment: Normally, without phantom power, plugging microphones in should be silent – not always, though. But you wouldn't be able to hear the output fine over the speakers. If that works already, the problem can only lie with the mixer. Have you tried comparing the lapel microphone and a shotgun microphone on the same channel? Another obvious reason would be a turned-down Aux send on the shotgun's channel.

Comment: I haven't tried comparing on the same channel. Good idea - I'll give that a go later.

Comment: Trying to picture your layout here...it's a little vague. Is it something like this?

Lapel Mic to Channel 1 of Mixer, Shotgun to Channel 2 of mixer. Both sources mixed to 2-channel mono, 1 source to the laptop and 1 to the house? That's how I would do it.

I'm wondering if perhaps this is a STEREO mix, with the shotgun panned, say, 70% to the house side of the mix? That would result in the house sounding fine, and if the lapel mic was panned to somewhere LESS than 70% of the house mix, it'd appear louder than the shotgun on the laptop feed.

Comment: Just confirmed that phantom power is on, all aux sends are turned up, tried shotgun Mic in lapel channel, and same problem

Comment: @Dwwilson, we are mixing the channels into a mono mix, and we're using one source for our main room, the other for a back room. The laptop is coming from an aux. I've checked that pan is set to neutral on all channels.

Comment: I think this is pointing to the Aux send to the laptop. Mics are OK, as you can hear them over the speakers. If you're mono and panned to center, the two channels out should sound similar. Have you tried taking the computer input from one of the channels going to the house (either the main or back room speakers) and seeing if you have louder output from that? This may be an issue of line level vs mic level from the Aux on the mixer or into Audacity (I'm not familiar enough with the software to know how it handles line/mic issues).

Comment: Also, you may want to bypass the Behringer USB...go direct into the laptop's mic input jack to test whether the Behringer is doing something stupid. I doubt it, since the lav records fine on the laptop...but worth a shot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2961/discussion-between-samuel-jack-and-dwwilson66)